# How do I override Click Funnel's Social Share url?

Tags: javascript, share-button

I need to pass a query parameter to my social buttons in click funnels.

It seems they init social shares within a closure.  How do I access these elements to change the url of the share buttons?

It does not respect `data-url`.  I change them, but no effect

Answer (score 0):

`data-url` is only read during initialization.

After that, `$('.social-likes').data('social-likes')` contains what you need.
Especially `.buttons[...].options`!

In the case you want to read an ID from your query and include that in a facebook link.

```
 var someId =  window.location.search.match(/someId=([\d]+)/);
 someId = someId && someId[1];
 var url = 'http://example.com/?someId=' + someId;


 $('.social-likes').each(function(){
    $($(this).data('social-likes').buttons).each(function(n, button){
      console.log('social button button', button);
      button.options.url = url;
    });
    console.log($(this).data('social-likes'));
    $(this).data('social-likes').options.url = url;
  });
```